# Subscript out of range error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
For i = 1 To wss.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    poc(i) = wss.Cells(srow + 3, scolumn).Value     
    wsd.Cells(drow, dcolumn).Value = poc(i)
    drow = drow + 1
Next
```

This is the error I get

> subscript out of range error

Comment: Most of the time you use `wss` but you also use `wsd` on one line. Are those two separate variables or is `wsd` a typo?

Comment: Also: use `Option Explicit` to avoid these types of errors.

Comment: This question should have more information. Which line shows the error? How are `drow`, `srow`, `dcolumn`, `scolumn` defined?

Comment: My bet is that the assignment to `poc(i) = wss.Cells(...` fails because `poc` is an array that has not been properly dimensioned (or redimensioned to the proper size). None of the other lines would raise that error. I would expect an error on `wsd.Cells` if, as @barrowc notes the possible typo, but this would be a 424 "Object Required" error.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable replies. My problem was resolved. I failed to redim the array... its works fine now

Answer (score 0):

The error is most probably due to the fact that your `poc` array is smaller than row count on `wss` worksheet. Please re-dimension to have at least the same number of items as `wss.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`.

Also, check if `wsd` reference is correct.